# __unsafe_unretained in struct

Tags: objective-c, c

Let say I have a struct in which I declare like so:

```
struct myStruct
{
    NSString *aString;
}
```

The above gives error.

I can, however, fix the error by:

```
struct myStruct
{
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *aString;
}
```

It silences the error, but will crash at runtime, because I suppose aString is immediately released.

I have tried `__strong` instead but it won't compile.

Is there any other way I can store an object within the struct and use it properly?

Comment: Don't use a `struct` with objects. Create a class so you get good memory management. Then you can also add properties and methods where they belong. Only use `struct` with non-Objective-C object types.

Comment: @rmaddy I agree with you. Trust me. But I would like to know if there is a way to make it possible.

Comment: You can't use strong pointers in C structs. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for reference. Is there no way around this?

Comment: use `__bridge_retained` when assigning a value to aString

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new object and use this as a pointer to a struct (as this is what a Objective C object is). So if you create a subclass of NSObject with instance variables that you require you can treat it exactly like a pointer to a structure (once you have initialised it). i.e.

```
myObj = [[myObjClass alloc] init];

myObj->instanceVariable1   = @"myString";
```

As mentioned in the comments below you need to declare the variables in the interface like this:

```
@interface myObjStruct : NSObject
{
  @public
  NSString *instanceVariable1;
}
```

With an NSString you can use a CFStringRef instead, or cast your `NSString *` to a CFString and retain it with a `CFRetain()`, or use `CFBridgingRetain` to get the incremented retain count immediately.  You can do this with any type that is toll free bridged from a CF type (such as CFArray CFDictionary).

```
struct testStruct {
  CFStringRef str;
};

- (void)aMethod
{
  NSString *string = @"Hello struct";
  struct testStruct test = {
    CFBridgingRetain(string),
  };
}
```

You now have ownership of the string, and will need to call `CFRelease` on the `test.str` at some point to not leak memory. To get a `NSString` back you cast it like this `NSString *string = (__bridge NSString *)test.str;`.

The above code has incremented the retain count of the string object. It's possible to get this to work for any object like this:

```
struct testStruct {
  __unsafe_unretained AnyObj *obj;
};

- (void)aMethod
  AnyObj *aObj = [[AnyObj alloc] init];
  CFBridgingRetain(aObj); \\increment the retain count.

  struct testStruct test = {
    aObj,
  };

  aObj = nil;

  NSLog(@"%@", aObj); 
}
```

To release this object later you would need to do `CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)(test.obj));`. Note that if you remove the `CFBridgingRetain(aObj);` this code will probably crash.

You could also try having a play with `id objc_retain(id value);` Although to use this you will need to manually include the arc.h header see [How to import objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581627/how-to-import-objc-retainautoreleasedreturnvalue) you would use this to increment the retain value much like the code above but without the need for casting. You'd also have to use the equivalent release function.

Comment: Can you show a bit how this can be done with `objc_retain(id value);` with arc.h?

Comment: As in the post pointed at you can find the arc.h header [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-551.1/) normally it's not visible, so you need to include the header into your own project.

Comment: One note: the ivar must be declared in the `@interface` as `@public` in order for outside objects to access it like this.

Comment: @JamesSnook Right, removing `CFBridgingRetain(aObj);` would definitely crash. Tested. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanations. Have a good one.

Comment: It won't always crash if you've got a constant string for instance the object will still exist at the memory location.

Answer (score 2):

[**Toll-Free Bridged Types**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010677)

> - __bridge transfers a pointer between Objective-C and Core Foundation with no transfer of ownership.
> - __bridge_retained or CFBridgingRetain casts an Objective-C pointer to a Core Foundation pointer and also transfers ownership to you. You are
>     responsible for calling CFRelease or a related function to relinquish
>     ownership of the object.
> - __bridge_transfer or CFBridgingRelease moves a non-Objective-C pointer to Objective-C and also transfers ownership to ARC. ARC is responsible
>     for relinquishing ownership of the object.

Example (not recommend)

It seems `__bridge_retained`, `__bridge_transfer` don't allow ownership transfer to/from same type. So I used additional __bridge for type casting.

I've test confirmed NSString objects are released without leaks.

```
#define TEST_COUNT 10000

struct myStruct
{
    NSString* __unsafe_unretained aString;
};

static struct myStruct* myArray = NULL;

static void allocString()
{
    myArray = (struct myStruct*) malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct) * TEST_COUNT);
    for (int i=0; i<TEST_COUNT; ++i)
    {
        NSString* v = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", i];
        myArray[i].aString = (__bridge NSString*)(__bridge_retained void*) v;
    }
}

static void freeString()
{
    if (myArray)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<TEST_COUNT; ++i)
        {
            if (myArray[i].aString)
            {
                NSString* v = (__bridge_transfer NSString*) (__bridge void*) myArray[i].aString;
                v = nil;
            }
        }
        free(myArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting that there isn't any leak. Let me go head and take a closer look at your answer. For now, +1. Thanks.